# Install new version of Ubuntu on a dual boot XP /Ubuntu 11.04 system

Tags: 12.04, installation

My computer does not support a USB boot. It is an HP Pavilion dz6000 laptop. How can I install version 12.04 on my system? The computer has a little less than 1GB memory. Is that enough? version 11.04 works well.

Comment: Do you have a CD drive? How about an internet connection?

Comment: Yes, both CD and internet. I have USB drives, but system does not suppor boot from USB. I have Ubuntu 12.04 loaded on a USB drive. I wanted to do fresh install but I found instructions for upgrade, so I might do that unless it is easy to do a fresh install.

Comment: I would personally, with only 1 GB of RAM, go for a lighter version of Ubuntu. Maybe Xubuntu or Lubuntu. Although you could also install [Cinnamon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)) over any Ubuntu if you prefer that. You should be able to install via your disk drive.

Comment: If you cannot boot from a USB flash drive, burn the ISO image to a CD and boot from that instead. See [How to burn a DVD on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu) and [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/22949). If you prefer to *upgrade* your existing system, you'll have to upgrade to 11.10 and then to 12.04; see [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/22949) For information on lighter-weight official derivatives, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/206407/22949).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Plop boot manager](http://www.plop.at/en/home.html)? I do believe you can burn an ISO image to a disk. Then, when you boot, make sure your USB boot drive is inserted, and boot from the Plop cd you burned. From there, tell PLOP to boot from USB. Even if you BIOS doesn't support USB, Plop will!